# How do we prove $\int \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^k}{k^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

After working on the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$ for a couple of hours, I became convinced its antiderivative was not elementary. So I looked it up on Wolfram Alpha, and it found that  $$\displaystyle{\int \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^k}{k^2} = -\text{Li}_2(-x)}.$$ How does one prove this result? I have no idea where to even begin...

Comment: *Hint:* What's the power series expansion of $\ln (1 + x)$?

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Use $\log(1+x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^k}{k}$ ,then integrate termwise.